# Can't see URL to specific image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

guys I want to send some photos to my friend but when I want copy specific photo URL from gallery, so I can copy just gallery URL no photo. Is there any way to change it to see URL for photo ? I attach some photos for better explain.

I tried to change permalinks in settings and also watched in gallery, but in gallery are no settings. But I found that gallery is using ModuloBox.

This is how is URL in gallery preview

[image: gallery URL]

Here you can see that URL is same like in gallery

[image: same URL]

And this is what I need (watch URL)

[image: What I need]

Comment: You should ask whoever supplied you the ModuloBox. Most likely your theme developer or your plugin developer.

Comment: tried right click and copy image address ?  or use developer tools to find the image url

Comment: developer tools are good Idea, but impracticable @cjmling

Answer (score 0):

There is a share option in the top right of your gallery which generates a link for you:

https://www.flyingslovak.eu/galleries/slovakia/?guid=photography_gallery_5273&mid=8

Comment: ye I know, but it's just for social media. There is no "Copy link"

Comment: If you click to share on twitter you get a pop up and can copy the link from there?

Comment: ye but it's impracticable when you want to send more than just one pic from more galleries

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open the image you want in the slider, then right clicking on the large image and choosing 'Open image on a new tab'? Not quite sure thats the right wording, but it is something like that.

In the new tab you get the URL for the image - something like www.example.eu/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/01.jpg